How to Handle Overflow in Double Scalars When Working with Very Large Numbers in Python?
I'm working on a data that involves computations with very large numbers, and I'm encountering an issue with numerical overflow and plotting. The problem arises when I increase the value of a parameter  (at the beginning of the code).
For example, with =5, my code runs perfectly without any errors and the curve is generated. However, as I gradually increase , parts of the plotted curve start to disappear. By the time  reaches 20, the curve disappears entirely. the problem is that I should use values for N=1000 or 2000.
the following error occurs
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars,
Here’s the python code:
import numpy as np
import cmath
import math
from math import e
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpmath
from scipy.special import gamma, factorial
import scipy.special as sc

N = 5 # VARIABLE OF INTEREST (SHOULD BE INCREASED)



g1, g2= 1.31928e-06, 4.947323e-07

H, ms = 1/6, 6

x_axis_points = np.arange(0, 40, 1)
E1 = 10.0 ** ((x_axis_points-30) / 10.0)/1e-11
y_axis_points = []
for QS in E1:
 
    A, B = N * 0.979405**2, N * 0.07986762

    w= (B/A)**2*(A**2/B)*(A**2/B+1)
    r= (B/A)**4*(A**2/B)*(A**2/B+1)*(A**2/B+2)*(A**2/B+3)


    f= w**2/ (r-w**2)
    c= g2**2 * QS*(r-w**2)/w
  


    BB=H *QS * g1**2
    L1, L2= 1/BB, 1/c


################### THE PROBLEM APPEARS IN THE COMMING LINES
#(GIVES INFINITY WHEN INCREASING N) ##############

    cons1= L1**(N*ms)/ sc.gamma(N*ms)  
    cons2= L2**(f)/ sc.gamma(f  )    

    sup3_num= L2**(f)*sc.gamma(N*ms+1   +  f)
    sup3_den= (N*ms+1)*( L2 + L1)**( N*ms+1 +f)               
    sup3=mpmath.hyp2f1(1, N*ms+1 + f, N*ms+1+1, L1/(L1+L2))

    sup4_num= L1**(N*ms)*sc.gamma(f+1   +  N*ms)
    sup4_den= (f+1)*( L2 + L1)**( f+1 +N*ms)                   
    sup4=mpmath.hyp2f1(1, f+1 + N*ms, f+1+1, L2/(L1+L2))



    Z1= cons1* sup3_num/sup3_den * sup3/ sc.gamma(f)

    Z2= cons2* sup4_num/sup4_den * sup4/ sc.gamma(N*ms)   
  
    y = math.log2(1+ Z1+Z2 ) 

    y_axis_points.append((y))            
plt.plot(x_axis_points, y_axis_points,    linewidth='2.5', color='blue')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()

plt.xlim([0, 40])
plt.ylim([0 , 3 ])
plt.show()


The code is not reproducible : there is a comment in the middle which is not commented and when we fix that, then there is another error : ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (40,) and (1,). Can you make this code reproducible first?

I guess the lines starting from ################### THE PROBLEM APPEARS ... up to and including y_axis_points.append((y)) need to be indented (so to be part of the for loop), or else the error that @JérômeRichard mentioned will happen

Thanks for the notes, it is fixed now

This is a very common problem when dealing with large factorials (or Gamma). In this case you can convert the expressions to logarithmic form taking advantage of the loggamma function.

Given that you need to handle numbers larger than the largest possible float, I would suggest using mpmath for more of this calculation.
Example:
import numpy as np
import cmath
import math
from math import e
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpmath
from scipy.special import gamma, factorial
import scipy.special as sc

N = 2000 # VARIABLE OF INTEREST (SHOULD BE INCREASED)



g1, g2= 1.31928e-06, 4.947323e-07

H, ms = 1/6, 6

x_axis_points = np.arange(0, 40, 1)
E1 = 10.0 ** ((x_axis_points-30) / 10.0)/1e-11
y_axis_points = []
for QS in E1:
 
    A, B = N * 0.979405**2, N * 0.07986762

    w= (B/A)**2*(A**2/B)*(A**2/B+1)
    r= (B/A)**4*(A**2/B)*(A**2/B+1)*(A**2/B+2)*(A**2/B+3)


    f= w**2/ (r-w**2)
    c= g2**2 * QS*(r-w**2)/w
  


    BB=H *QS * g1**2
    L1, L2= 1/BB, 1/c


################### THE PROBLEM APPEARS IN THE COMMING LINES
#(GIVES INFINITY WHEN INCREASING N) ##############

    cons1= mpmath.power(L1, (N*ms))/ mpmath.gamma(N*ms)
    cons2= mpmath.power(L2, (f))/ mpmath.gamma(f)

    sup3_num= mpmath.power(L2, (f))*mpmath.gamma(N*ms+1   +  f)
    sup3_den= (N*ms+1)*mpmath.power(( L2 + L1), ( N*ms+1 +f))
    sup3=mpmath.hyp2f1(1, N*ms+1 + f, N*ms+1+1, L1/(L1+L2))

    sup4_num= mpmath.power(L1, (N*ms))*mpmath.gamma(f+1   +  N*ms)
    sup4_den= (f+1)*mpmath.power(( L2 + L1), ( f+1 +N*ms))
    sup4=mpmath.hyp2f1(1, f+1 + N*ms, f+1+1, L2/(L1+L2))



    Z1= cons1* sup3_num / sup3_den * sup3 / mpmath.gamma(f)

    Z2= cons2* sup4_num / sup4_den * sup4 / mpmath.gamma(N*ms)   
  
    y = mpmath.log1p(Z1 + Z2) / mpmath.log(2)

    y_axis_points.append(float(y))            
plt.plot(x_axis_points, y_axis_points,    linewidth='2.5', color='blue')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()

plt.xlim([0, 40])
# plt.ylim([0 , 3 ])
plt.show()

